# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter doesn't inflate results coming from Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` to retrieve data from a Firestore Collection named `hello`. Each document in the collection contains a single String field called `name`.

The problem is, `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is not displaying anything. The data is fetching fine if I do not use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and try to retrieve it with Snapshots.

This is the code I am using to display the data with `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`

```java
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("hello");

        query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onEvent: " + value);
            }
        });


        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CategoryModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryModel>()
                .setQuery(query, CategoryModel.class)
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<CategoryModel, CategoryHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CategoryModel model) {
                holder.textView.setText(model.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public CategoryHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup group, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item, group, false);
                return new CategoryHolder(view);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                super.onDataChanged();
                categoryRV.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "I got called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };



        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        categoryRV.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public static class CategoryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public CategoryHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

My xml code:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/categoryRV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_19sdp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_19sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lbl_explore"
            tools:listitem="@layout/category_item" />
```

My Model Class:

```java
    public class CategoryModel {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is my Firestore Database:

[image: Firestore Database]

Only `onDataChanged()` is getting called, apart from that, no method gets called.

Comment: Have you set a `LinearLayoutManager` for your RecyclerView?

Comment: @AlexMamo, thank you. I missed setting the LinearLayoutManager for the RecyclerView

Comment: And does it work now, with the LinearLayoutManager?